# Neper number into postscript code

Tags: pstricks

I need to plot this function:

```
f(x)=e^(5,61+x/1000)
```

using `pst-plot`, where `e` is Euler's costant but I don't know how to write it in postscript code. Anyone knows how?

Comment: However, this function will need a huge graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PostScript code (reverse polish notation) of your function looks like this:

```
Euler 5.61 x 1000 div add exp
```

*Euler* is a pre-defined constant available in pstricks.

Comment: You're welcome. Please think about accepting this answer if it solved your problem. :)